# Random Sonar analysis fail with "Failed to download analysis cache"

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, drone.io

I am facing a recurrent and yet random problem during the sonarqube analysis step of a Drone CI build.

Here is the .drone.yaml part:

```
- name: code-analysis
  image: aosapps/drone-sonar-plugin
  settings:
     sonar_host:
       from_secret: sonar_host
     sonar_token:
       from_secret: sonar_token
```

And sometimes, this analysis fail with this stacktrace, sometimes if I restart the same build it passes, sometimes not (completely random indeed):

```
INFO: Load active rules

INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=7329ms

INFO: Load analysis cache

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: Total time: 42.448s

INFO: Final Memory: 17M/241M

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@7db12bb6-org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@7db12bb6-org.sonar.scanner.report.AnalysisCachePublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'WriteCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provideWriter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ReadCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.cache.ReadCache]: Factory method 'provideReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)

    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:135)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)

    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)

    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)

    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)

    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@7db12bb6-org.sonar.scanner.report.AnalysisCachePublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'WriteCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provideWriter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ReadCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.cache.ReadCache]: Factory method 'provideReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1437)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)

    ... 31 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'WriteCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provideWriter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ReadCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.cache.ReadCache]: Factory method 'provideReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)

    ... 48 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ReadCache' defined in org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.cache.ReadCache]: Factory method 'provideReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)

    ... 62 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.cache.ReadCache]: Factory method 'provideReader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)

    ... 76 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to download analysis cache

    at org.sonar.scanner.cache.DefaultAnalysisCacheLoader.load(DefaultAnalysisCacheLoader.java:92)

    at org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheMemoryStorage.load(AnalysisCacheMemoryStorage.java:52)

    at org.sonar.scanner.cache.AnalysisCacheProvider.provideReader(AnalysisCacheProvider.java:35)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)

    ... 77 more

exit status 1
```

As I can't find anything I'm asking you, does that happen to you ? also, why does it happen and how to fix it?

Many thanks. :)